# Data table ordena mal las horas

Tags: jquery, datatable

Estaba probando la libreria jquery de datatable's que esta bastante completa y buena, relacionado a la propiedad de que se puede ordenar de manera ascendente a descendente los datos, ingrese datos de hora, como 7:15 AM, 8:00 AM, 9:00 AM, 9:45 AM, me di cuenta que la columna donde tiene ese tipo de dato, ordena de forma erronea la tabla, es decir, pone primero las 9:00 AM y despues las 8:40 AM por ejemplo.

¿como podria solucionar esto? para que ordene de forma correcta el campo

Anexo el [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/EQqgaq?editors=1010) que hice para que me comprendan de mejor manera

Comment: No es que lo ordene mal, simplemente lo esta ordenando por orden alfabético

Comment: Los datos que introduces al datatable son dinámicos o estáticos?

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara pues por el momento son estáticos

Comment: @Klaimmore pero al ser números no los debería ordenar de mayor a menor? es decir, el 8 antes del 9

Comment: Así es los ordena de menor a mayor, si agregas "sType": "string", pero ocurre el problema que cuando son las 10 am lo pone primero, es como si las 10 fuera menor que las 8 am, lo que se me ocurre es que ingreses los valores de forma estática y quites el ordenamiento automático para que te muestre el datatable tal cual lo creaste.

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara esa era la "solución" que se me había ocurrido, quitarle lo de que se ordene, ¿es posible quitárselo únicamente a ciertas columnas?

Comment: Si claro, ahora te escribo una respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, gracias :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finales del 2014, [Datatables](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) depreco funciones override para hacer el tema de ordenamiento de fechas y los "reemplazo" sugiriendo usar [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)  para efectuar la operación. Para usarla solo tienes que hacer referencia al script de momentjs y antes de inicializar tu **Datatable** usar la función **$.fn.dataTable.moment()** que recibira el formato de fecha que deseas ordenar.
Ten en cuenta el orden en los cuales se llaman los script ya que sino lo haces en ese orden te saltara un error por referencia.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.moment('h:mm A');
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>  
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Hora Inicio</th>
              <th>Hora Final</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Hora Inicio</th>
              <th>Hora Final</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td> 7:15 AM </td>
              <td> 8:00 AM </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 8:00 AM </td>
              <td> 8:40 AM </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 8:40 AM </td>
              <td> 9:00 AM </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 9:00 AM </td>
              <td> 9:45 AM </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 9:45 AM </td>
              <td> 10:30 AM </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> 10:30 AM </td>
              <td> 10:35 AM </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución simple y rápida es dar orden estático, y quitar al auto-ordenamiento, de paso te pongo el idioma que es lo que le falta tambien.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   var idioma = {
"sProcessing": "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
"sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
"sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
"sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
"sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
"sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
"sInfoPostFix": "",
"sSearch": "Buscar:",
"sUrl": "",
"sInfoThousands": ",",
"sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
"oPaginate": {
    "sFirst": "Primero",
    "sLast": "Último",
    "sNext": "Siguiente",
    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
},
"oAria": {
    "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
},
buttons: {
    copyTitle: 'Los datos fueron copiados',
    copyInfo: {
        _: 'Copiados %d filas al portapapeles',
        1: 'Copiado 1 fila al portapapeles',
    }
}
}


  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "language": idioma
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Data table ejemplo para pregunta</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css'>

  
  
</head>

<body>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <br>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
       <table id="example" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Hora Inicio</th>
             <th>Hora Final</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
           <tr>
             <th>Hora Inicio</th>
             <th>Hora Final</th>
           </tr>
         </tfoot>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td> 7:15 AM </td>
             <td> 8:00 AM </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td> 8:00 AM </td>
             <td> 8:40 AM </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td> 8:40 AM </td>
             <td> 9:00 AM </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td> 9:00 AM </td>
             <td> 9:45 AM </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td> 9:45 AM </td>
             <td> 10:30 AM </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td> 10:30 AM </td>
             <td> 10:35 AM </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```